# Crashlytics version string meaning

Tags: crashlytics

I know this might be a stupid question, but:

In Crashlytics I see next to my versions:

[image]

What do those numbers 31/39/43/55 means?
That's not my version codes, while 2.5.1/2.6 etc. are my version names.

Comment: number of crashes in that version

Comment: Oh, number of total crashes per version, sure. Thanks, @chiragshah and you can put it as an answer!

Comment: will you pls accept my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Crashanalytics number indicate new version is number of same crashes in other version too.